# Power BI classification column that adapts to slicer filters

Tags: matrix, filter, classification

I've seen similar questions being asker, but none seem to answer my problem. I have a database that looks like this:

[image]

I want to classify clients by their sales behavior year to year (for example, if the client sold more in 2023 than 2022, I want it to classify as "Increase"). Then, i want to have this classification as rows in a matrix visualization. As the end result, I want something like this:

[image]

I've managed to create a calculated column that does this in the database. But i want the classification to adapt if I filter in a slicer. For example, in my example, if I filter UK, I want it to say "Decrease". If I do this as a calculated column, it wont change based on the filter. I don't think i can have it as a measure either, since I cant add the measure as a line in the visualization. Is it possible to do this in Power BI?

*SOLUTION*: I based my solution on what Nick.McDermaid posted. My problem was slightly different, I didn't want the classification inside each year, and I wanted my classification to be based on True/False conditions. I made a support table like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0ifZ.png)

And used the following DAX to get the number of customers per category (I also replicated it to get the other information I want on the table).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHaBq.png)

As a result, I got something like this, where I could also later see the customers in each category and adapt the classification filtering on the other fields:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZD6.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand the rules you want to apply, but you can definitely change calcs based on slicers, this is one of the advanteges if DAX over SQL. This site will have a pattern that does what you need. https://www.daxpatterns.com/

Comment: Sorry, I added an image to be clearer. My problem is I dont think I can do this as a measure, because than I can only add that as values on the vizualizations, not as rows 
 or column groupings.

Comment: This might be what you're after. https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/ if it is, _please_ document your answer here because we can never get enough examples of these cryptic DAX solutions

Comment: If you could post a summary as an  answer, that will help many people